# There VS Therein VS in there

Tags: adverbs

What is the difference between:

1) I found a wallet. There was some money there.

2) I found a wallet. There was some money therein.

3) I found a wallet. There was some money in there.

Answer (score 3):

They all mean essentially the same thing - that there was money found along with the wallet.

1) "there" - this is the only slightly ambiguous one. There was money "there" - I guess this could mean "in the general area where I found the wallet," though it's more likely the money was inside the wallet.

2) "therein" - there was money inside the wallet. "Therein" sounds a little pompous to me. It's a more formal or archaic-sounding way of saying "in there."

3) "in there" - there was money inside the wallet. This sounds the most natural of the three sentences to me. I'd probably actually say "There was some money inside" or "There was some money in it."

Comment: Thank You a lot!

I will ask some other "there" questions now but in the new questions cause this commenting area isn't published very nice. So if You could help me again - please do, follow my new questions, friend=)